# Decomposition of the exterior algebra of a representation of $Sp(1)\times GL(n,\mathbb{H})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $H:=\mathbb{C}^2$ be the standard representation of $Sp(1)$ and $E^\ast:=\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be the standard dual representation of $GL(n,\mathbb{H})$. Then $H\otimes E^\ast$ is a representation of $Sp(1)\times GL(n,\mathbb{H})$. Both representations carry an invariant quaternionic structure $J$ and $H$ carries an invariant symplectic form $\sigma_H$ with $\sigma_H(Jh_1,Jh_2)=\overline{\sigma_H(h_1,h_2)}$ and $\sigma_H(h,Jh)>0$ for all $h\neq 0$, i.e. $h\mapsto \sigma_H (h,\cdot)$ is an equivariant ismorphism $H\rightarrow H^\ast$.

How do I get the decomposition of the exterior algebra $\bigwedge\nolimits^k(H\otimes E^\ast)=\bigoplus_{2n\geq a\geq b\geq 0, a+b=k} Sym^{a-b}H\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{a,b} E^\ast$ where $Sym^{a-b}H$ are the symmetric tensors and $\bigwedge\nolimits^{a,b} E^\ast$ is the kernel of a $GL(n,\mathbb{H})$-equivariant map $Pl:\bigwedge\nolimits^{a} E^\ast\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{b} E^\ast\rightarrow \bigwedge\nolimits^{a+1} E^\ast\otimes \bigwedge\nolimits^{b-1} E^\ast$ without using Schur functors. Is there an explicit isomorphism of these $Sp(1)\times GL(n,\mathbb{H})$-representations?

I assume that $Pl$ is the map $e_1^1\wedge \dots\wedge e_1^a\otimes e_2^1\wedge \dots\wedge e_2^b\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^b e_1^1\wedge \dots\wedge e_1^a\wedge e_2^i\otimes e_2^1\wedge \dots\wedge \hat{e_2^i}\wedge\dots\wedge e_2^b$.